# Using a column alias in an INNER JOIN query?

Tags: mysql, inner-join, alias

My query:

```
SELECT Name, A, B, C, D, E, F 
FROM Data 
INNER JOIN User_Access ON Data.Name = User_Access.Name 
WHERE User_Access.Channel = 'TEST'
```

I have to use an alias for "Name" but I cannot.

My best almost-answer:

```
SELECT Name AS N, A, B, C, D, E, F 
FROM Data 
INNER JOIN User_Access ON Data.N = User_Access.Name 
WHERE User_Access.Channel = 'TEST'
```

But it's not working and I have an invalid name error.

How do I use a column alias in an INNER JOIN query?

Comment: You don't have to use an alias for name but you do need to qualify name either with the table name or an aliased table name,

Comment: Can you try some other name other than N. Guess N is also ambiguous in your case. If it doesn't work kindly share your  schema of those two tables. Thanks

Comment: Table aliases in FROM are different from column aliases in SELECT. PS You aren't explaining what you want. Wrong code is not helpful. "use an alias" is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where a column name is common between n tables you need to qualify it so that sql knows which one you mean.This will work

```
SELECT data.Name, A, B, C, D, E, F 
FROM Data 
    INNER JOIN User_Access ON Data.Name = User_Access.Name 
WHERE User_Access.Channel = 'TEST'
```

as will

```
SELECT d.Name, A, B, C, D, E, F 
FROM Data d
    INNER JOIN User_Access ON d.Name = User_Access.Name 
WHERE User_Access.Channel = 'TEST'
```

Comment: Thank you, it's works very well ! I red your first comment but I didn't understood what you wanted to say with "qualify column name". As at the end of the SELECT, we write "FROM Data", I didn't know that it was useful to qualify Name from Data with "Data.Name"

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT User_Access.Name, A, B, C, D, E, F 
FROM Data 
    INNER JOIN User_Access ON Data.N = User_Access.Name 
WHERE User_Access.Channel = 'TEST'
```

I have replaced the Name (as is key word) with User_Access.Name (changing the column name that is appending with the actual table's name).

Answer (score 0):

From [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement):

> The following steps show the logical processing order, or binding
>   order, for a SELECT statement. This order determines when the objects
>   defined in one step are made available to the clauses in subsequent
>   steps. For example, if the query processor can bind to (access) the
>   tables or views defined in the FROM clause, these objects and their
>   columns are made available to all subsequent steps. Conversely,
>   because the SELECT clause is step 8, any column aliases or derived
>   columns defined in that clause cannot be referenced by preceding
>   clauses. However, they can be referenced by subsequent clauses such as
>   the ORDER BY clause. The actual physical execution of the statement is
>   determined by the query processor and the order may vary from this
>   list.
>
> 1. FROM
> 2. ON
> 3. JOIN
> 4. WHERE
> 5. GROUP BY
> 6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
> 7. HAVING
> 8. SELECT
> 9. DISTINCT
> 10. ORDER BY
> 11. TOP

Notice that the `SELECT` is in position 8, where as `JOIN` and `ON` are in positions 3 and 2 respectively. Therefore you **cannot** reference a column by it's alias defined in the `SELECT` in the `ON`; as the `SELECT` hasn't been processed yet. Effectively, the only place you can reference a column by it's alias (in the same scope) is in the `ORDER BY`.

If you *really* wanted to to this, you could use as `CROSS APPLY` and `VALUES` operator, but (honestly) you wanting to type `N` instead of `Name` in the `ON` is more laziness:

```
SELECT V.N, D.A, D.B, D.C, D.D, D.E, D.F --I assume there are all from the Data table
FROM Data D
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES(D.[Name])) V(N)
    INNER JOIN User_Access UA ON V.N = UA.Name 
WHERE UA.Channel = 'TEST';
```

Answer (score 0):

`Name` is a reserved word, you need to enclose that in square bracket

```
SELECT [Name], A, B, C, D, E, F 
FROM Data 
    INNER JOIN User_Access ON Data.N = User_Access.Name 
WHERE User_Access.Channel = 'TEST'
```

Comment: *"you need to enclose that in square bracket"* no, you don't. [Reserved Keywords (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). It is a *keyword* but it is not, however, a ***Reserved** Keyword*. Therefore it doesn't need to be delimit identified. Many do, in case it becomes a Reserved Keyword, but it is not currently planned ([Future Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#future-keywords)).